# Bash to split string and numbering it just like Python enumerate function

Tags: bash

I found interesting way to split string using `tr` or `IFS`

https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-split-string/

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to split a string based on the delimiter

my_string="One;Two;Three"
my_array=($(echo $my_string | tr ";" "\n"))

#Print the split string
for i in "${my_array[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Output

```
One
Two
Three
```

Based on this code, would be be possible to put a number in front of the string by using Bash?

In Python, there is `enumerate` function to accomplish this.

```
number = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

for i,j in enumerate(number, 1):
    print(f'{i} - {j}')
```

Output

```
1 - One
2 - Two
3 - Three
```

I belive there should be similar tricks can be done in Bash Shell probably with `awk` or `sed`, but I just can't think the solution for now.

Comment: `echo $((++c)) - $i` ?  You'll need to change to `printf "%03d - %d\n", $((++c))  $i` to have zero padded numbers past 100. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just add something like `count=$(($count+1))`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to split a string based on the delimiter

my_string="One;Two;Three"
my_array=($(echo $my_string | tr ";" "\n"))

#Print the split string
count=0
for i in "${my_array[@]}"
do
    count=$(($count+1))
    echo $count - $i
done
```

Comment: Cool, simpler solution. Didn't think about this before

Comment: In BASH, you can simply write `((count++))`, and you don't need to restore explicitely the value in `count`. Therefore the loop can contain only one command: `for i in "${my_array[@]}"; do echo $((++count)) - $i; done`

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly modified version of @anubhava's answer.

```
y_string="One;Two;Three"

IFS=';' read -ra my_array <<< "$my_string"

# ${!array_name[@]} returns the indices/keys of the array
for i in "${!my_array[@]}"
do
    echo "$((i+1)) - ${my_array[i]}"
done
```

From the bash manual,

> It is possible to obtain the keys (indices) of an array as well as the values. ${!name[@]} and ${!name[*]} expand to the indices assigned in array variable name.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you posted a post earlier today, sorry I failed to upload the code but still hope this could help you

```
my_string="AA-BBB"
IFS='-' read -ra my_array <<< "$my_string"
len=${#my_array[@]}
for (( i=0; i<$len; i++ )); do
    up=$(($i % 2))
    #echo $up
    if [ $up -eq 0 ]
    then 
        echo ${my_array[i]} = '"Country name"'
    elif [ $up -eq 1 ] 
    then
        echo ${my_array[i]} = '"City name"'
    fi
done
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard bash way of doing this:

```sh
my_string="One;Two;Three"

IFS=';' read -ra my_array <<< "$my_string"
# builds my_array='([0]="One" [1]="Two" [2]="Three")'

# loop through array and print index+1 with element
# ${#my_array[@]} is length of the array
for ((i=0; i<${#my_array[@]}; i++)); do
    printf '%d: %s\n' $((i+1)) "${my_array[i]}"
done
```

```
1: One
2: Two
3: Three
```